# Access to Editor Script of a Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that `target` is used to access the `MonoBehaviour` of the `Editor`. But how do I access the `Editor` script from a `MonoBehaviour`?

Is it even **POSSIBLE**?

**SITUATION :-**

I have a `ScriptableObject` that has to be set up in a `MonoBehaviour` script.

> This `ScriptableObject` contains settings for creating gizmos.

Currently, I am doing it in the **Editor** [`OnEnable()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.OnEnable.html). It works. But, when I reset the script from the Unity Inspector, Unity starts throwing `NullRefererenceException` because this resets the `ScriptableObject` to **null**.

So, I want to set up that *reference* from the `Editor` whenever [`Reset()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) method is called for the `MonoBehaviour` script.

**CODE :-**

MonoBehaviour:

```cs
public GizmosConfiguration gizmosConfig;
```

Editor:

```cs
public GizmosConfiguration gizmosConfiguration;

public void OnEnable()
{
    // setting up the gizmos configuration in the script
    gS.gizmosConfig = gizmosConfiguration;
}
```

> I want to set up `GizmosConfiguration` through the editor when the `Reset()` method is called from the `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Quite unclear what you are trying.. could you add the code you have so far which is causing the issue?

Comment: @derHugo No code is causing an issue. I want to set up a `ScriptableObject` through the editor when the Reset() method is called from the MonoBehaviour.

Comment: I don't understand why you would do that ... where does the `gizmosConfiguration` in the editor come from originally? Why not simply assign it as the default reference vis the Inspector of the component script itself? Afaik this should make `Reset` assign that default reference (might be wrong though) .. there is no way to get the editor for a certain MonoBehaviour .. what if there are multiple ones? You know you can lock Inspector tabs and add new ones .. or there might be none at all (e.g. if in debug mode) so what you are trying to do seems quite unreliable

Comment: I am using a custom inspector. Also, I want to assign such *references* through the Editor. I just want to get a reference to the Editor in the `Monobehaviour` script. This way, I could assign the `GizmosConfiguration` in the `MonoBehaviour` Reset().

Comment: Again.. this way you can't and shouldn't.. and again - I get this is a custom editor - what do you want to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I am sorry. If I was not able to explain it properly. I want to reassign the `GizmosConfiguration` through the editor. It is not necessary to use the way I thought was possible. Isn't there any other way such as to use an interface etc. or anything else?

Comment: why not just keep the reference around and in case you executed `Reset` reassign that previous SO? It's still hard for me to understand what the actual underlying goal is you are trying to achieve or think you have to achieve this way .. there might be another better way but for that we would need to know what problem you are actually targeting to solve by that .. see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: *"why not just keep the reference around and in case you executed Reset reassign that previous SO?"* That is exactly what I want. Sorry for the inconvenience. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

the `MonoBehaviour` of the `Editor`? No.
What exactly are you trying to do? If you can be more specific.

Comment: No, I want to access the `Editor` from the `MonoBehaviour`. Edited the question for the second.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what exactly you are trying to achieve. Why do you need it? What you are trying to do after?